# Laravel can't upload File

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I build a Laravel Application. I have a file-upload-form where users can upload images or videos.

I made The following settings in th php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M 
post_max_size = 32M
```

My validation rules:

```
$mime = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalExtension();
if ($mime == "png" || $mime == "jpg" || $mime == "jpeg") {
    $rules["file"] = "required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1024";
} elseif ($mime == "mp4" || $mime == "webm") {
    $rules["file"] = "required|file|mimes:webm,mp4|max:32768";
}
```

I handle the upload with

```
$request->file("file")->store("uploads");
```

Following Scenarios:

- When I upload a image everything works well
- When I upload a really small video (500kb) everything works well
- When I upload a 5MB video I get the following ErrorMessage

> The file failed to upload.

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx? Did you find any relevant information in the server's logs? (not the app's one)

Comment: You might also want to check the `max_execution_time` -
 if file takes longer to upload, although with 5MB this shouldn't really cause a problem - http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: try to echo `phpinfo()` function and see is it really updated your the values for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. if yes then try to `print_r($_FILES)` and see the error code.